# mysqldump (using PHP exec) not dumping file but no error

Tags: mysql, php, exec

I wasn't sure if this was a SO or SF question but I thought this might be the best place. I apologise if it is not!

I am using mysqldump through PHP exec but it doesn't seem to be working. The code I am using is

```
<?php
exec('mysqldump -u DB_USER -pDB_PASS DB_NAME > /tmp/test.sql');
?>
```

When I run this script I recieve no errors on error_log, but I do not get a dump in /tmp. I am not sure what is causing this. I am not sure if it is trying to dump to /tmp relative to where the PHP file is being executed, which is the result I am looking for, or is dumping to a /tmp elsewhere? Or am I making another mistake completely?

Comment: Try to use the absolute path to `mysqldump` command in the script. You can find it by running `whereis mysqldump`. Also make sure username/password is correct.

Comment: I've found the issue! It is dumping to the /tmp in the root of my server, and not where the php script is situated!

Answer (score 13):

The solution I found is to run the command in a sub-shell and then output the `stderr` to `stdout`. This way, the `$output` is well populated.

i.e. :

```
exec("(mysqldump -u$username -p$password $database $tables > $dump_name) 2>&1", $output, $result);

var_dump($result);
echo "<br />";
var_dump($output);
echo "<br />";
```

The output :

> int(6)
>
> array(1) { [0]=> string(46) "mysqldump: Couldn't find table: "table_name"" }

Hope it helps !

Comment: This is GOLD!!!

Comment: Man, I was looking for this trick for months, thaaaaaank you you are a genius

Comment: Handy method for debugging.

Comment: Jeez, what a simple trick, but would never have known it if I didn't find it here - THANKYOU!!!

Comment: I want to second Mohd Abdul Mujib... This was truly GOLD! Thank you.

Comment: I would like to point out that the error is not present in `$output` without having the entire dump command wrapped in brackets. Life saver!

Answer (score 1):

The path you have declared (`/tmp/test.sql`) is an absolute path so the script is behaving correctly. As for linux file system `/` defines the root directory and there always exists a `/tmp` directory. May be you should take a little time to understand [General overview of the Linux file system](http://tldp.org/LDP/intro-linux/html/sect_03_01.html).

> The tree of the file system starts at the trunk or slash, indicated by
>   a forward slash (/). This directory, containing all underlying
>   directories and files, is also called the root directory or "the root"
>   of the file system.

As for dumping the file to a relative directory, you can try to use `./tmp/test.sql` or `tmp/test.sql`, if the `tmp` directory resides at the current directory from where the script is run.

You may have a look at this too: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17407664/php-include-relative-path